# Combining two regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a question about accomplishing something in regular expressions i.e is it possible and if so how.

Short synopsis of what I am doing: I read Manga online. I like to open up the current issue in a new tab but I don't always remember to click the link with a middle click.

So I decided to write a Greasemonkey script that would run on any of the sites pages adding a `target="_blank"` to any anchor tag that references a manga or an issue of that manga so a regular click would open it in a new tab. The script itself is working fine, nothing spectacular about it.

Now onto the caveat:

The link patterns we'll call it for each Manga is as follows

```
    <language of manga>/<manga name> 
      links to the main about page for the manga

    <language of manga>/<manga name>/<issue number> 
      links to the issue number itself

    <language of manga>/<manga name>/<issue number>/<page number> 
      links to the specific page of the issue
```

Now I want it to always make the first two open in a new tab but I do NOT want the last one to open in a new tab. The reason for this is when reading the actual Manga each click to advance the page would open a new tab.

So to accomplish this I have two regular expressions:

```js
    var MangaIssueRegex = /en-manga\/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\//;
    var MangaIssuePageRegex = /en-manga\/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\/(\d+\/){2}/
```

The first regex picks up any of the three manga link patterns.
The second regex picks up only the third manga link pattern (the one for a specific page)

In a nutshell the Greasemonkey script loops through all the anchor tags on the page when it loads and if the href attribute of the anchor tag passes the MangaIssueRegex AND fails the MangaIssuePageRegex the anchor tag is modified to open in a new tab otherwise the anchor tag is not modified.

Now is it possible to combine both regular expressions into a single one that will match the first two patterns but fail if the third pattern is encountered?

Here is the whole script:

```
    var MangaIssueRegex = /en-manga\/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\//;
    var MangaIssuePageRegex = /en-manga\/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\/(\d+\/){2}/
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
      if (MangaIssueRegex.test(elements[i].getAttribute("href")) && !MangaIssuePageRegex.test(elements[i].getAttribute("href")))
      {
        elements[i].setAttribute("target","_blank");
        elements[i].setAttribute("title","Opens in another tab");
      }
    }
```

### Update

Thanks to both @DanielHilgarth and @iMoses for helping me figure this out

I found out I can use jQuery in Greasemonkey so in the end this is what I ended up with as the complete working script

```js
$("a")
  .filter(function(){return /en-manga\/[\w\-]+\/(\d+\/)?$/.test(this.href);})
  .each(function(index){$(this).attr({title:"Opens in new tab",target:"_blank"});});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For matching only the first two patterns try using:

```
var MangaIssuePageRegex = /en-manga\/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\/(\d+\/)?$/
```

This will match:

```
<language of manga>/<manga name>
```

As well as:

```
<language of manga>/<manga name>/<issue number>
```

If you don't wish to enforce a closing backslash, use this Regex instead:

```
var MangaIssuePageRegex = /en-manga\/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+(\/\d+)?(\/)?$/
```

Comment: As to the first post by @DanielHilgarth, it will also match:
en-manga/asd/asd-12/
Which I'm not sure is desired, because you said the second value needs to be a number.
As to my answer, it forces you to have a closing backslash at the end of the string (as I thought was desired by your example). If this is an unwanted behavior you should use this regex instead:

`var MangaIssuePageRegex = /en-manga\/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+(\/\d+)?(\/)?$/`

If this was not the problem then I don't know what is. According to my testing and retesting this regex only matches your first two examples.

Comment: You are right my friend I'm not sure why when i copied your regex into my code it didn't work the first time but I double checked and it's perfect

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just add the text end anchor at the end?

Something like this:

```
/en-manga\/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+\/){1,2}$/
```

This would match

```
en-manga/asd/
en-manga/asd/12/
```

But not

```
en-manga/asd/12/123/
```

You can test it [yourself](http://regexr.com?30d2s).

Comment: So what does the $/ do exactly?

Comment: Basically, it tells the regex engine that the input text needs to end at that position for the input text to be a match. Just try removing the `$` in the link I provided. You will see that it matches all four examples, although only part of the last two, but they are still a match.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to match the first regex when it ends, in which case try changing it to:

```
var MangaIssueRegex = /en-manga\/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\/?$/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTGuB/1/

Comment: That cuts off both the second and the third pattern I only wanted to cut off the third pattern

Comment: Ahh yes, in which case a single character edit will sort that out. I'll make the change above.